# Как сформировать заголовок для GET запроса ajax

Tags: ajax, auth

Вот рабочий заголовок сформирован с помощью POSTMAN для авторизации на RestFull сервере

```
GET /v1/auth/init HTTP/1.1
Host: test.key4.com.ua:8080
UserAuthorization: Bearer 5G18NTBRMEQXHUMT2D3FWR
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

вот пробую отправить с помощью ajax

```
  var result = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        url: base_url + url,
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('UserAuthorization', 'Bearer 5G18NTBRMEQXZCTHD3FWR');
        }
    }).responseJSON;
```

Но он не отрабатывает возвращает 401 видимо не правильно формирует заголовок
Вот какой получается

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, userauthorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:test.key4.com.ua:8080
Origin:http://test.com.ua
```

Comment: посмотрите в браузере, какой именно запрос уходит. Это можно посмотреть в Инструментах разработчика на вкладке Сеть или Network

Comment: @Grundy добавил в вопрос

Comment: 401 - unauthorized. Возможно ваш токен устарел..

Comment: @nikita Его вообще не видно в заголовках, хотя я добавляю

Answer (score 1):

Вы отправляете кросс-доменный ajax запрос. Соответственно, браузер добавляет к вашему запросу заголовок Origin. Если сервер готов с вами работать (принимать запросы с вашего домена) то он (сервер) должен ответить вам, присовокупив к ответу заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin в котором должен быть адрес вашего домена либо *. В этом случае браузер сочтет что удаленный сервер разрешает вам кроссдоменное общение. В противном случае браузер посчитает что апрос завершился с ошибкой и вызовет обработчик ошибок.

я попробовал воспроизвести ваш код. заголовок отправляется, однако сервер отвечает на запрос без заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin. В этом и проблема. Кроме того, синхронные запросы считаются устаревшими. Используйте асинхронные обработчики. Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Что-то ваш "пример" пустой.

Answer (score 0):

Вы столкнулись с [preflight request](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B) из за того, что добавили "непростой" заголовок

Comment: Хотя нет, наверное я не угадал.

Comment: Я не знаю изучение этого вопроса требует много времени, думаю, решил вообще не использовать клиент для отправки данных

Answer (score -1):

> Его вообще не видно в заголовках, хотя я добавляю

А вы точно правильно отслеживаете заголовки? Для подобного лучше юзать сниффер Fiddler, он работает на уровне системы и показывает всё.

А по теме: я в таких случаях сперва всегда пробую более низкоуровневое API, т.к. по нему обычно больше исходников и прочей инфы (ибо оно старше). В данном случае это XmlHttpRequest. Что насчет него? С его помощью можете отправить такой заголовок?